# Is it ok to make a python librairy that uses an other one?

Tags: python, libraries

I'm making a python project that will allow you to deploy/update easily a continuous integration environment on a server.

Jenkins, Git, Gerrit, Sonar, doku wiki, web server.
with jenkins who autobuild what is pushed to gerrit and display the result of the build/unit test on gerrit.

At first it was for me but then I though, hey why no make it accessible for everyone.

I'm using paramiko to do ssh, is this a bad practice to release a librairy wich needs something that is not native to python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether questions about bad practice are to be posted here, but still -

**Legally**

Paramiko seems to be maintained under LGPL, which means that any free or proprietary software is allowed to link paramiko. So legally everything is allright.

**Good practice**

You should only question yourself whether the library you rely on is a well-maintained one and you should let every possible user of your library know, that there is a requirement and provide users with a way to get the requirement (e. g. a link to download, script to run to install, etc.).

Using non-native libraries when creating a library is a very common and normal thing to do - you are not supposed to reinvent a wheel :)